# Bound for $GL(3)$ symmetric square

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions

Let $\pi$ be an automorphic representation of $GL(3)$ over a number field. Let $a_n$ be the coefficients of $L(s, \pi, \mathrm{sym}^2)$. Do we know if

$$\sum_{n>0} \frac{|a_n|}{n^s}$$

and

$$\sum_{n>0} \frac{\left( \sum_{k \mid n} |a_k|\right)^2}{n^s}$$

converge for $\Re(s)>1$? or even for $\Re(s)>1+\delta$ for a quite small $\delta$?

This essentially amounts to say that the coefficients are constant on average. It seems to be known for Gelbart-Jacquet lifts by Rankin-Selberg properties, but is it known or at least expected for non-Gelbart-Jacquet lifts?

Comment: We certainly expect this, and it would follow from special cases of Langlands functoriality. Proving it is a different matter.

Comment: @GHfromMO I would have guessed that $|a_n|$ is majorized by the $n$-th Dirichlet coefficient of $L(s,\pi\times\widetilde{\pi})$, or perhaps something "close" to that (at least for $\pi$ without ramification).  This guess is based on the factorization $L(s,\pi\times\widetilde{\pi})=L(s,\pi,\mathrm{Sym}^2)L(s,\pi,\mathrm{Ext}^2)$ and the nonnegativity of the coefficients of $L(s,\pi\times\widetilde{\pi})$.  Is there an easy way to see that this approach fails?

Comment: @2734364041: I haven't thought about this, and I don't have time to think about it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\pi$ be a cuspidal automorphic representation of $\mathrm{GL}_m$ with unitary central character.  In work of Takeda, it is shown that the (unramified part of the) $L$-function $L(s,\pi,\mathrm{Sym}^2)$ is holomorphic in the region $\mathrm{Re}(s) > 1-\frac{1}{2m}$.  Taking $m=3$, we find that your first series converges for $\mathrm{Re}(s)>1$.

The second series is obviously a little trickier, but we can get there in the special case where $\pi$ is self-dual.  In this case, $\pi$ is a Hecke character twist of the symmetric square lift of a cuspidal automorphic representation $\pi'$ on $\mathrm{GL}_2$.  Suppose (for now) that $\pi=\mathrm{Sym}^2\pi'$ and $\pi$ has level 1 (so $\pi'$ is nondihedral).  Then $\mathrm{Sym}^2\pi = 1\boxplus \mathrm{Sym}^4 \pi'$, in which case

$L(s,\pi,\mathrm{Sym}^2) = \zeta_F(s) L(s,\mathrm{Sym}^4\pi')$.

Note that $\mathrm{Sym}^4\pi'$ is a cuspidal automorphic representation of $\mathrm{GL}_5$.  Thus $\Pi = 1\boxplus \mathrm{Sym}^4 \pi'$ is an automorphic representation of $\mathrm{GL}_6$, and the $L$-function

$L(s,\Pi\times\tilde{\Pi}) = \zeta_F(s)L(s,\mathrm{Sym}^4\pi')^2 L(s,\mathrm{Sym}^4\pi'\times \mathrm{Sym}^4\pi')$

converges absolutely for $\mathrm{Re}(s)>1$.  The $n$-th Dirichlet coefficient $\lambda_{\Pi\times\tilde{\Pi}}(n)$ is bounded below by $|a_n|^2$.  A Dirichlet convolution calculation shows that if $s>1$, then the series is bounded above by

$L(s,\Pi\times\tilde{\Pi})\zeta_F(s)^2$

(or maybe 2 needs to be replaced with a higher power?), which converges absolutely for $\mathrm{Re}(s)>1$.

*Takeda, Shuichiro*, [**The twisted symmetric square (L)-function of (\mathrm{GL}(r))**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1215/00127094-2405497), Duke Math. J. 163, No. 1, 175-266 (2014). [ZBL1316.11037](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1316.11037).